# Usage of だろうと in this sentence?

Tags: particle-と

> その態度を見ると分かってるみたいだけど彼の許可なくあんな言ったら当事者だろうとアウティング同然だぞ

So I understand the sentence is akin to "it looks like, after you saw the current state, you understand it, however if you say those things without his permission, it will be as the same as outing him."

For context, the character in question spoke about 彼 dating life and thus outed him in the process.

Why is だろうと used here?

Answer (score 3):

- [(よ)うと is "even if ～"](https://www.guide2japanese.com/%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%83%BB%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%83%BB%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C/), so だろうと is "even if it's ～". So 当事者だろうと means "even if you're a 当事者". 当事者 sounds like a legal term, but it's sometimes used casually in the sense of "someone actually involved in the matter". Here, it indicates that the listener was not just aware of his hidden fact, but was also involved in the matter in some way (e.g., being received a romantic confession).
- The subject of 見る is the speaker. その態度を見ると分かってるみたいだ means "Judging from your attitude, it seems like you understand this".

> その態度を見ると分かってるみたいだけど、彼の許可なくあんな言ったら、**当事者だろうと**アウティング同然だぞ。
>
> Judging from your attitude, it seems like you understand this, but **even if you're (directly) involved in this matter**, saying such a thing without his permission is practically the same as outing!

Comment: +1 just want to say だろうと here is just a variant of だとしても

Answer (score 1):

I will first say that I've never seen “同然だ” used that way rather than “も同然だ” and that use  of “あんな” also looks strange to me and should at least be “あんなの(を)” I feel. Did you copy the text correctly?

Regardless This usage of “ようと” is essentially the same as “〜ようが”, “〜ても or “〜たって”. It's formed by attaching “〜と” to the volitional form of af a verb and can be seen as to mean “regardless” in essence. So it means something like “Saying such things without his permission is no different from outing him, whether you were involved or not.”.

It can be used with any verb so “あの子がいようと” and “あの子がいても” have very comparable meaning but I'd say the former is more literary and formal than the latter. “〜ようが” is on a similar level of formality and “〜たって” is the most emphatic and least formal of them.

It should be noted that there is also another “〜ようと” with an entirely different meaning to it which is simply which indicates what one attempts to do, as in “服を買おうと来た。” for “I came here in order to buy clothes.

Comment: I checked and there is no も but you are right about あんなの

Comment: [N]同然 is not uncommon.

Comment: I understood あんな naturally as あんなに but it turned out it to be あんなの as you thought...

Comment: @aguijonazo huh, the more you know I guess. The も is required with a verb? Or is “死んでる同然だ” also possible?

Comment: No, it must be 死んでる（の）も同然.